# No such method error only in raspberry pi

Tags: java, javafx-2, raspberry-pi

fed up with raspberry pi.....

i have created a javaFX application from windows 7 using netbeans 7.3.1 , jdk 1.7 ..

application has included some external jar including javafx-dialogs-0.0.3,jaybird etc..

its all works fine with windows 7,ubuntu and centOS

Then i tried to run the same application jar from command line in raspberry pi..
but it gives Exception like `"noSuchMethoderror` " and exiting the application..

what may be the issue ???

am using same jar during comple and run time..

here is full stack

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.getPseudoclassMask(Ljava/lang/String;)J
at javafx.scene.control.Dialogs$FXDialog$RootPane.<clinit>(Dialogs.java:1310)
at javafx.scene.control.Dialogs$FXDialog.<init>(Dialogs.java:1131)
at javafx.scene.control.Dialogs$FXDialog.<init>(Dialogs.java:1088)
at javafx.scene.control.Dialogs$DialogTemplate.<init>(Dialogs.java:616)
at javafx.scene.control.Dialogs.showSimpleContentDialog(Dialogs.java:494)
at javafx.scene.control.Dialogs.showInformationDialog(Dialogs.java:266)
at displayshelftry.Utilities.propertySettings(Utilities.java:325)
at displayshelftry.DisplayShelfTry.run(DisplayShelfTry.java:356)
at displayshelftry.DisplayShelfTry.start(DisplayShelfTry.java:1150)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:331)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:297)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication$RunnableEvent.dispatch(LensApplication.java:182)
at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication._runLoop(LensApplication.java:861)
at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication.access$1700(LensApplication.java:58)
at com.sun.glass.ui.lens.LensApplication$4.run(LensApplication.java:914)
... 1 more
```

thanks...

Comment: Would be useful to have full stack.

Comment: wait i wili provide it

Comment: i have edited the question with full stack

Comment: which JavaFX version you are using ?

Comment: java 1.8 is using with raspberry pi   .. i thing it has javafx support

Answer (score 1):

Try building you app with jdk8. jdk8 usually should run jdk7 built jars as well, but it's not yet released and rasberry pi was supported only since jdk8.

Also official pi vs javafx page claims that not all demos will work on pi (note it's not yet released product): https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi

So you may want to try BrickBreaker instead of DisplayShelf :)

Comment: this displayShelf is my own program... not javafx sample